# How to install mercure in Symfony project?

Tags: symfony4, ubuntu-20.04, mercure

I am trying to implment Symfony Mercure in my local environment. I am following official documentation `https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html`

So accordingly I downloaded binary from link `https://github.com/dunglas/mercure/releases/tag/v0.11.3`

From the download I copy mercure & CaddyFile.dev to symfony bin folder and then I execute following lines:

```
$ SERVER_NAME=:3000 MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=key MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=key ./bin/mercure run -config Caddyfile.dev
```

But I am getting `bash: ./bin/mercure: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Late I changed to

```
$ MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=key MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=key ./bin/mercure run -config bin/Caddyfile.dev
```

This returns me error `run: loading initial config: loading new config: http app module: start: tcp: listening on :443: listen tcp :443: bind: permission denied`

Can anybody already implemented it. Please help.

Thanks.